# How to create a counter in Excel online (Excel 365)

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I know to use Active X and buttons to create a counter that when clicked increments by 1 in normal Excel easily enough but excel 365(online) doesn't allow for buttons. Any idea how to create a counter in Excel online?

So I found this bit of code but I don't know Javascript. Anybody know enough that can be of help?

```
Public xRgS, xRgD As Range
Public xNum As Long
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Set xRgS = Range("E2")
    If xRgS Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set xRgD = Range("H2")
    If xRgD Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(xRgS, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    xNum = xNum + 1
    xRgD.Value = xNum
End Sub
```

It just keeps track of everytime you click inside a cell.

Comment: You may have to think outside the box on this one and use the JavaScript API.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins

Comment: Yea I was thinking about being able to use onMouseOver to just increment it but implementing that to an excel spreadsheet is more confusing than I was expecting.

Comment: This is VBA, not JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified. I don't know Javascript to be able to convert this VBA code to Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible ways for O365 on the web:

- Create a web add-in where you can develop a custom UI (it can be a task pane) with a counter, see [Build an Excel task pane add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-jquery?tabs=yeomangenerator).
- Use Office scripts, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/vba-differences for more information.

I suppose web add-ins is the right choice for a custom UI (a task pane).